# How to add class by javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to add class by module.scss by this do not work properly. I know that I have good path because adding innerHtml working.

```
import styles from './style.module.scss';
(...)
useEffect(() => {
  document
    .querySelector('.thisButtonAddClass')
    .querySelector('div')
    .querySelector('input')
    .classList.add(styles.btn);
}, []);
```

Main problem is that I want to style react-mailchimp-subscribe and I have no clue how to access to the html tags.

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing native JS DOM methods and React like that. You should show your JSX and the expected output.

Answer (score -1):

styles is object, for classList.add you must use string with name of class

or use React like style:

```
<input className={styles.btn} />
```

But, in my opinion, you are using useEffect with native js incorrectly.

And it's best to pack the render of this input into a separate function, something like this:

```
const renderInput = () => {
    const [flag, setFlag] = React.useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setFlag(true)
    }, []);

    return (
        <input className={flag?styles.btn1:styles.btn2} />
    )
}
```

Comment: Although true, that still isn't the way OP should solve the problem.